# Javascript regex assistance

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following javascript regex...

```
.replace("/^(a-zA-Z\-)/gi", '');
```

It isn't complete... in fact it's wrong.  Essentially what I need to do is take a string like "XJ FC-X35 (1492)" and remove the () and it's contents and the whitespace before the parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
replace(/^(.*?)\s?\(([^)]+)\)$/gi, "$1$2")
```

Takes XJ FC-X35 (1492) and returns XJ FC-X351492.

Remove the `$2` to turn XJ FC-X35 (1492) into XJ FC-X35, if that's what you wanted instead.

### Long explanation

```
^   // From the start of the string
(   // Capture a group ($1)
.*? // That contains 0 or more elements (non-greedy)
)   // Finish group $1
\s? // Followed by 0 or 1 whitespace characters
\(  // Followed by a "("
(   // Capture a group ($2)
[   // That contains any characters in the following set
^)  // Not a ")"
]+  // One or more times
)   // Finish group $2
\)$ // Followed by a ")" followed by the end of the string.
```

Comment: +1 for a robust regexp, and for providing alternatives depending on what the OP meant. But do you really need to match and replace the initial `^(.*?)`? Why not just omit it?

Comment: @LarsH - Habit more than anything else.  I always prefer, when dealing with regular expressions to make sure that I'm grabbing what I want, rather than removing what I don't (whitelist, don't blacklist).  You are correct though - the `^(.*?)` and `$` could be removed without harm resulting in the easier to read `replace(/\s?\(([^)]+)\)/gi, "$1")` -- and it's up to the fair reader to choose the better way.

Comment: nice bit-by-bit explanation. Btw I preferred your earlier `\s*` over `\s?`, since the OP's "the whitespace" is pretty ambiguous as to cardinality. I would have put `\s+` but you may be right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x = "XJ FC-X35 (1492)"
x.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)/,'');
```